# Convert base64 string to PDF in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pdf, base64

I am unable to open a base64 string as pdf in angular application if the file size is more than say 10mb. The browser crashes with a page saying "AW, SNAP". The base64 string i.e. "base64content" already has the metadata at the start and looks something like this:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQK...DUKJSVFT0YK
```

I am using below way to open the base64 string as a PDF in new tab:

```
$window.open(base64content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the base64 string was too big for the browser to interpret. This is because the pdf was heavy(more than 2mb) the approx max limit of browser. The solution was to use blob based approach.

Answer (score 6):

Try with

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64content);
```

Comment: My base 64 string already has this metadata at the start. It looks like this:    data:application/pdf;base64,JVSSSRi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9EZWNvZGVQYXJ…dlMDVlYTITTTTT533ECctfgNTQzYWFjOSSSTMwMTRiM2RhZDk5Pl0+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNjk1ODUKJSVFT0YK